# Convert string to date

Tags: vb.net, string, date

I have a Web service that receives dates on this format dd/MM/yyyy.

I realized that it crash cause sometimes I have dates like this one 1/1/2012.

I have no control on what the web service receives.

I tried

```
    myDate = cDate(myString)

    myDate = Convert.toDatetime(myString)

    myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)

    myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(myString.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

Nothing works, so is there any elegant way to do this or I have to split and add "0" when it's a date like this

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myString, 
                             "d/M/yyyy", 
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                             DateTimeStyles.None)
```

It also works for "01/02/2012", "21/1/2012", "1/11/2012" and "12/12/2012".

Comment: yeah but sometimes it will be dd/m/yyyy, d/mm/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy like 21/1/2012, 1/11/2012 or 12/12/2012 :(

Comment: @Marc - the above will parse all of these fine.

Comment: @Marc - Doesn't matter. "d/M/yyyy" will catch all of those. "dd/MM/yyyy" will only work when your input is always 01/01/2012.

Comment: The force is strong with this one.

Comment: @JimH. I moved the webservice on another server and now I have this error Server was unable to process request. ---> The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar for 27/3/2012. Any ideas?

Comment: @Oded I moved the webservice on another server and now I have this error Server was unable to process request. ---> The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar for 27/3/2012. Any ideas?

Comment: @Marc - I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Should this be Date.ParseExtract, rather than DateTime.ParseExtract?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateAsString, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 0):

ACCESS SQL DATE QUERY SOLVED

Convert String Date To Access SQL Date

When trying to select data from an SQL query in my project, the date was formatted as: 31/01/2014 04:46:54, the field column was declared as datetime in the database...

however when I used an sql statement fldPlaceOrderDate = #31/01/2014 04:46:54#
It would not return any rows. When I would view the column in microsoft access it would display it the same way. So I concluded there must be a bug with my SQL in my vb project right?

So I copied the SQL from my vb.net project into the access query builder sql view, and it didn't return any rows there either. So I built the SQL again manually using the MS Access Design View. I formatted the date the same #31/01/2014 04:46:54# ... this time it returned the row, and it showed the date was actually formatted as MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss

So I tried the following instead in my project

"SELECT fldReference" & VBCRLF & _
"FROM tblOrders"  & VBCRLF & _
"WHERE fldPlaceOrderDate = #" & CDATE("31/01/2014 04:46:54").ToString("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss") & "#;"

This fixed the problem!